# Vertical ScrollBar in javafx TableView is not working

Tags: scrollbar, javafx, tableview

I'm using the javafx version that comes with jdk 1.8.0, build 97. I have created a TableView at the center of a BorderPane. Its horizontal scrollbar works fine. But when the vertical scrollbar appears when I resize my screen, it takes up the entire length of the vertical scrolling track, and will not move. Likewise, clicking on the scroll up and scroll down buttons on the vertical scrolling track has no effect. However, when I scroll up and down with my fingers on my laptop's touchpad, that works just fine. Does anyone have any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely some nodes on the outside of the BorderPane are overlapping your content.  You can test this by setting the center of the BorderPane last, in which case the center will overlap the border.  In general I don't really like BorderPane that much because I find the way it tries to fit components into minimal space non-intuitive and stick with VBox and HBox where I can.

Also note that the above behaviour may not be your particular issue.  Java 8 is currently early access software which may have bugs.  Your description sounds like you may have found a bug.  If, after further testing, you feel it is a platform bug, create an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) and include it in a [bug report](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/issues/?jql=text%20~%20Scroll%20ORDER%20BY%20updated%20DESC), with your description of how to replicate the issue.

Comment: You're right! It's a bug. I tried creating the same TableView in Java 7, and it worked just fine. I submitted a bug report https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-31812

Answer (score 2):

By creating the same TableView in Java 7, I determined that this scrolling behavior was a bug. The bug has since been fixed. TableView scroll bars function normally in Java 8, build 99.